# svg.js rotation center of clipped element

Tags: javascript, svg, svg.js

Svg.js animation of rotations [works great](http://jsfiddle.net/heyzeuss/EfRcV/13) because it uses the center point of the element by default, even when the element is moving from one spot to another, but now I'm [having trouble](http://jsfiddle.net/heyzeuss/evL6v/13/) when I add a clipping path to an image, because the center point is still the center of the original image, even if it is outside of the clipping path. I would like to use the center point of the clipping path instead. The closest thing I could find was [a question about d3.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21412043/how-do-i-rotate-or-scale-transform-an-svg-path-relative-to-its-center-point).

```
var rect = draw.rect(60,60)
var picture = draw.image(img.jpg).clipWith(rect)
picture.animate(1000).rotate(360)
```

How can I get it working in svg.js?

Comment: Can you post a fiddle or something?  It's not quite clear what is happening.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a centre of rotation to the `rotate()` method.  All you have to do is work out where the centre of the clip rect is and pass that in. It works out to be 90,80.

```
this.animate(1000).rotate(
    360 + currentRotation, 90,80
)
```

[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/evL6v/16/)

For some reason it doesn't work the first time, but after that it works fine.  That seems like a bug in svg.js.

Comment: After much experimentation http://jsfiddle.net/heyzeuss/evL6v/18/, I found that the object SVG.rbox will get me the center point, but only at the beginning of the animation. If I want the clipped element to move from point 'A' to point 'B' it does not anymore rotate about its own center. The center of rotation *should* move with the element, as in the first example of the question.

Comment: The mentioned bug was fixed a while ago